# Can spring statemachine support multi configuration?

Tags: spring-statemachine

In my project, i have a problem; i have many scenes in which i need to support multi status configuration, for example, i need to define create order status machine and i also need to define create item status; so can any one tell me how can i do with spring statemachine?

i already use `@EnableStateMachineFactory` and define

`@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
@SuppressWarnings("all")
public class OrderHoldConfiguration extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<HoldState, HoldEvent> {
... 
}`

`@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class JsdConfiguration extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<BizState, BizEvent> {
...
}`

but it don't work, which way should i use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like docs are a bit unclear on this but both `@EnableStateMachine` and `@EnableStateMachineFactory` work in a same way where resulting beans are named `stateMachine` and `stateMachineFactory` respectively. In your case other factory simple gets overridden.

```
@EnableStateMachineFactory(name = "factory1"){}
@EnableStateMachineFactory(name = "factory2"){}
```

Then you can autowire or get bean from spring app context just like any other bean by name. There is existing ticket [gh-306](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/issues/306) to allow autowiring by generic types so until that gets fixed you need to wire by name (i.e using `@Qualifier`).

Comment: Is there an example or documentation on how to integrate a single state machine  service (DefaultStateMachineService implementation) with two factories (each one containing a distinct state machine model)?